# Do wands in Baldur's Gate have limited charges?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-2

I did not see any description in-game about the number of charges left in a magic wand, neither did I find anything in the manual or online. I tried out a few wands (wand of missiles, lightning, etc.), but after a few dozen uses I got bored.

Do magic wands and wand-like magic items (necklance that shoots fireballs, etc.) have really unlimited charges? I'm talking about BG1, but I'm interested for an answer for BG2 as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, as in official DnD rules, unless it states otherwise in the wand's description, wands have a limited number of charges.** According to [the answer here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/75251-baldurs-gate/48343527),

> Yes, wands have limited charges. One charge is used every time you use the wand (unless the item description says that it uses more charges). The number of charges can vary anywhere from 10-50.
>
> BG1 does not show the number of charges left, so it is just guesswork to determine how many charges you have left. BG2...shows the number of charges if you have the wand in a quick-slot.
>
> Sorcerous Sundries, an arcane shop in the city of Baldur's Gate, sells an unlimited quantity of all the wands in the game. So you don't need to be stingy with wand usage, since you can just buy more when they run out.

and

> You can easily recharge wands by selling them and then immediately buying them back, or stealing them...

Obviously a shop that has infinite supply and sell/buy to recharge are both in violation of Official DnD rules, but they do exist in these games.

Also, while there is no direct way of checking the charges left in a wand in the first Baldur's Gate, you can infer how many charges are left in a wand by the amount that a wand will sell for.

Comment: I have yet to find a list of all the wands and their max charges for BG and BG2. If I do come across/create one, I will add that into this answer.

Comment: A was aware that wands should have limited charges, so I used them exceptionally sparingly. Good to know they are limited but the limit is quite high, so I'm free to make better use of them. Köszönöm!

Comment: @vsz Keep in mind though that wands picked up from loot often have a few charges used already (to simulate the previous owner having used them some) so while the wand may have a reasonable limit, the number of remaining charges could still be few. I still try to keep the wands I find most useful on reserve. In BG2 you're doing so much more damage than the wands that they become less important than thy were in BG.